# Align box content to bottom in html to PDF - no flexbox

Tags: html, css, node.js, phantomjs

I have a box with a static height containing 3 other boxes, first and last with static height, the one in the middle is dynamic.

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: keep-all;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.returnsPolicy {
    height: 33mm;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: smaller;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    /*position: relative;*/
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.returnsHeaderRow {
    height: 4mm;
    line-height: 4mm;
    font-weight: bold;
    /*margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;*/
}

.returnsDisclaimerRow {
    height: 4mm;
    line-height: 4mm;
    /*position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;*/
}

.returnsMainContent {
    max-height: 20mm;
    height: auto;
    /*position: absolute;
    bottom: 4mm;*/
}

<div class="returnsPolicy">
    <p class="returnsHeaderRow">
        <b>
            We want every customer to be totally satisfied with their purchase.
        </b>
    </p>
    <p class="returnsMainContent">
        If you change your mind about your purchase, please return the unused goods to us with the original proof of
        purchase within 45 days, and we will offer you an *exchange or a refund. This does not affect your statutory
        rights, including your right to claim a refund, repair or exchange where the goods are faulty or misdescribed.
    </p>
    <p class="returnsDisclaimerRow">
        *Excluding all shoe care products
    </p>
</div>
```

The commented parts in the css are some things I've tried unsuccesfully.

This would be really easy using flexbox, but I'm trying to convert some html to a PDF on a Node instance using html-pdf, which in turn uses PhantomJS, and for some reason the flex positioning is not working correctly after printing (if I try to preview on a browser the result using flex, it works as I want it too)

Place this in `.returnsPolicy` styles, and on a regular modern browser it works.

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

But sadly that's not my case.

returnsMainContent is the box that has dynamic content, and my goal is to align everything to the bottom. This is a footer, and I want it to take as little space as possible, but if my text does not fill the area in returnsMainContent, then I will have some empty space after returnsDisclaimerRow.

By using relative/absolute positioning I can place returnsDisclaimerRow and returnsMainContent to be bottom aligned, but then returnsHeaderRow cannot be positioned with absolute values, and the result is a white space between it and the returnsMainContent.

One solution could be adding an additional dynamic paragraph containing only white space that will expand and push to the bottom the other paragraphs, but when I tried I ended up covering other paragraphs...

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is simply to add a wrapper div for your content, and this is this wrapper div that you set with `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`. All the content inside can then take its place in the flow.

You only have to be careful that the content in the wrapper div does not get bigger in height than `.returnsPolicy`, as it won't adapt to the size, but that doesn't seem to be your case.

```css
    div {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        word-break: keep-all;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .returnsPolicy {
        height: 33mm;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: smaller;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 1mm;
        position: relative;
    }

    .returnsPolicyWrap {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    p {
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        white-space: normal;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    .returnsHeaderRow {
        height: 4mm;
        line-height: 4mm;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .returnsDisclaimerRow {
        height: 4mm;
        line-height: 4mm;
    }

    .returnsMainContent {
        max-height: 20mm;
        height: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="returnsPolicy">
  <div class="returnsPolicyWrap">
    <p class="returnsHeaderRow">
        <b>
            We want every customer to be totally satisfied with their purchase.
        </b>
    </p>
    <p class="returnsMainContent">
        If you change your mind about your purchase, please return the unused goods to us with the original proof of
        purchase within 45 days, and we will offer you an *exchange or a refund. This does not affect your statutory
        rights, including your right to claim a refund, repair or exchange where the goods are faulty or misdescribed.
    </p>
    <p class="returnsDisclaimerRow">
        *Excluding all shoe care products
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It had to be this simple :P Thanks